# ESD problem and how to solve

Tags: voltage, electromagnetism, ethernet, esd, phy

We have a problem with contact discharge of 3kV on a housing part. The PCB with the PHY are installed in an aluminum lower part with plastic upper part (dimensions approx. 80x80x80mm). The contact discharge occurs on the aluminum and a magnetic field is created which disturbs the PHY so that it loses its connection. Two conditions can occur:

1. the PHY detects the loss of the link. In this case, we can perform a reset of the PHY.
2. the PHY continues to display a link (via the status bits), but can no longer communicate. In this case, we cannot perform a reset because we do not know that the PHY is no longer talking. Disconnecting the Ethernet line solves the problem, because at that moment we detect the interruption and perform a reset. A PON also solves the problem (but practically no solution for the customer). Thus, the PHY does not have a general defect.

[image]

Picture_1 shows the PCB with the PHY. The housing is grounded and the shield of the Ethernet cable also goes to ground.We also see with contact discharge that the link LED lights up when the Ethernet cable is open at the other end.

[image]

Comment: Earth the aluminum part. If you have done so, pictures and diagrams of the setup are going to be needed.

Comment: This cannot be answered without pictures and a (simplified) schematic. What is grounded where, what inputs are exposed etc.

Comment: Added the schematic @Lundin

Comment: @Newbie Still doesn't explain how/if this is grounded to chassis. Are the shielded cables too as part of the product? ESD problems are almost always caused by ungrounded metal parts close to the PCB. What's the "LC03_3V3_TVS" thing? Is it LC03-3.3?

Comment: How do you know it is the magnetic field causing the issue? Usually it’s the discharge finding it’s way back to ground through a path you don’t want or suspect.

Comment: @Lundin added the setup image

Comment: Isn't the transformer connected the wrong way around? Who knows what else is wrong.

Comment: @Justme, is it? I believe it is connected correctly

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the shield and the "secondary" side towards Ethernet are grounded to chassis. But the other end of the shield will not necessarily be grounded. The rest of the PCB is grounded towards the power ground but not with chassis. Is this correct?